# Different spacing after periods

Tags: spacing

My problem is different spacing after periods. I only hit space one time, however spacing between period and next letter is not constant in entire document. How can I make it constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use \frenchspacing

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

abc abc. abc

\frenchspacing
abc abc. abc

\end{document}
```

[image]